# My AUTO_INCREMENT in phpMyAdmin is stuck at 1

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, phpmyadmin

Using XAMPP to run a MySQL server. Editing it with phpMyAdmin.
I am trying to increment a 'Wavelength(nm)' column by 10 however despite trying various forms of 
`` ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = 10 ; `` the values just keep incrementing by 1.
I have tried turning the auto increment on and off, going into the operations tab and setting manually the next value as 10 more (it goes up by 10 once then just resets).
The column is set to Int. 
I am using this MySQL database to store incoming data from a serial port. The serial terminal I have is in Visual Studio hence to communicate with the database I'm utilising the MySQL Connector NET extension. The received data is going into the 'R/T' column and each measurement is taken every 10nm; which is why I desire the 10 auto_increment. 
I'm quite new to C# and SQL in general but my feeling is that this problem is easier to fix in phpMyAdmin rather than in Visual Studio.

Comment: Please read documentation;  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html  `To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value...` AUTO_INCREMENT does NOT increment by that value, its FROM that value you set. If you need anything else, you need to program it yourself differently. Just of top of my head, check view's where you can generate custom data in columns, triggers etc...

Comment: @ikiK ah that makes a lot more sense thank you! I will check that out

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to change the auto_increment increment :)

`SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;`

Mind you this is a global variable and it applies to all tables

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I just tried this however the auto_increment increment just resets to 1. 
I used `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` and it would say the auto_increment_increment is 1. I followed the steps here [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-source.html) too and couldn't seem to get it working.

Comment: For the time being I managed to set the auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset manually in the my.cnf file

Comment: conf file is better way to that anyhow - its a global variable. happy to help